# What is the default smartirs for gensim TfidfModel?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, information-retrieval, tf-idf

Using `gensim`:

```
from gensim.models import TfidfModel
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary

sent0 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog .".lower().split()
sent1 = "Mr brown jumps over the lazy fox .".lower().split()

dataset = [sent0, sent1]
vocab = Dictionary(dataset)
corpus = [vocab.doc2bow(sent) for sent in dataset] 
model = TfidfModel(corpus)

# To retrieve the same pd.DataFrame format.
documents_tfidf_lol = [{vocab[word_idx]:tfidf_value for word_idx, tfidf_value in sent} for sent in model[corpus]]
documents_tfidf = pd.DataFrame(documents_tfidf_lol)
documents_tfidf.fillna(0, inplace=True)

documents_tfidf
```

[out]:

```
    dog mr  quick
0   0.707107    0.0 0.707107
1   0.000000    1.0 0.000000
```

If we do the TF-IDF computation manually,

```
sent0 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog .".lower().split()
sent1 = "Mr brown jumps over the lazy fox .".lower().split()

documents = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list(map(Counter, [sent0, sent1])))
documents.fillna(0, inplace=True, downcast='infer')
documents = documents.apply(lambda x: x/sum(x))  # Normalize the TF.
documents.head()

# To compute the IDF for all words.
num_sentences, num_words = documents.shape

idf_vector = [] # Lets save an ordered list of IDFS w.r.t. order of the column names.

for word in documents:
  word_idf = math.log(num_sentences/len(documents[word].nonzero()[0]))
  idf_vector.append(word_idf)

# Compute the TF-IDF table.
documents_tfidf = pd.DataFrame(documents.as_matrix() * np.array(idf_vector), 
                               columns=list(documents))
documents_tfidf
```

[out]:

```
    .   brown   dog fox jumps   lazy    mr  over    quick   the
0   0.0 0.0 0.693147    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.0 0.693147    0.0
1   0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.693147    0.0 0.000000    0.0
```

If we use `math.log2` instead of `math.log`:

```
    .   brown   dog fox jumps   lazy    mr  over    quick   the
0   0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

It looks like `gensim`:

- remove the non-salient words from the TF-IDF model, it's evident when we `print(model[corpus])`
- maybe the log base seem to be different from the log_2
- maybe there's some normalization going on.

Looking at https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.html#gensim.models.tfidfmodel.TfidfModel , the `smart` scheme difference would have output different values but it's not clear in the docs what is the default value.

**What is the default smartirs for gensim TfidfModel?**

**What are the other default parameters that've caused the difference between a natively implemented TF-IDF and gensim's?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value of `smartirs` is None, but if you follow the code, it is equal to **ntc**.

*But how?*

First, when you call `model = TfidfModel(corpus)`, it calculates IDF of the corpus with a function called `wglobal` which explained in docs as:

`wglobal` is function for global weighting, the default value is [`df2idf()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.html#gensim.models.tfidfmodel.df2idf). `df2idf` is a function that computes IDF for a term with the given document frequency. The default arguman and formula for `df2idf` is:

```
df2idf(docfreq, totaldocs, log_base=2.0, add=0.0)
```

[image: df2idf formula]

which implemented as:

```
idfs = add + np.log(float(totaldocs) / docfreq) / np.log(log_base)
```

One of the smartirs is determined:  document frequency weighting is inverse-document-frequency or **`idf`**.

---

`wlocals` by default is [`identity`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.identity) function. Term frequency of the corpus passed through the identify function which nothing happened, and the corpus itself return. Hence, another parameter of smartirs, term frequency weighing, is natural or **`n`**. Now that we have term frequency and inverse-document-frequency we can compute tfidf:

[image: tfidf formula]

---

[`normalize`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.html#gensim.models.tfidfmodel.smartirs_normalize) by default is true that means after computing TfIDF it normalizes the tfidf vectors. The normalization is done with `l2-norm` (Euclidean unit norm) which means our last smartirs is cosine or **`c`**. This part implemented as:

```
# vec(term_id, value) is tfidf result
length = 1.0 * math.sqrt(sum(val ** 2 for _, val in vec))
normalize_by_length = [(termid, val / length) for termid, val in vec]
```

---

When you call [`model[corpus]`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.html#gensim.models.tfidfmodel.TfidfModel.__getitem__) or [`model.__getitem__()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/tfidfmodel.html#gensim.models.tfidfmodel.TfidfModel.__getitem__) the following things happen:

`__getitem__` has a `eps` argument which is a threshold value that will remove all entries that have tfidf-value less than `eps`. By default, this value is 1e-12. As a result, when you print the vectors only some of them appeared.

Comment: Argh... Forgot to assign the bounty... Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'll redo a bounty and assign you the points =)

Comment: I suppose this is no longer true with gensim 4.1.2. I am getting different values when executing TfidfModel(BoW_corpus, smartirs='ntc') VS TfidfModel(BoW_corpus)